# Erro em conversão de notação infixa para posfixa

Tags: c

Ao inserir (3+7)   o resultado da operação é 37+ e ao colocar apenas 3+7 sem os parentes da erro de segmentação e quando  coloco (3+7)-(2+7) da erro também e não estou achando o erro. 
Gostaria de uma ajudinha.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50

/*estrutura pilha*/
struct pilha{
    double valor;
    struct pilha *proximo;
};
typedef struct pilha pilha;

/*outras funções*/
int bemFormada (char string[]);
char *infixaParaPosfixa (char infixa[]);
void trocaPorParenteses (char *string);
double calculo (char* posfixa);

/*funcoes da pilha*/
pilha * criaElemento(double valor);
void empilha(pilha ** p, pilha* e);
double desempilha(pilha ** p);
void mostrarPilha(pilha* p);

int main (){

    char infixa[MAX];
    char *posfixa;

    printf("================================================================================\n");
    printf("====================================Calculadora=================================\n");
    printf("================================================================================\n");

    /*entrada de dados*/
    printf("\n\n\nEntre com a expressao que desejada calcular: \n");
    gets(infixa);
    fflush(stdin);

    /*testa se bem formada, se for, realiza outras funções, se não, fecha o programa*/
    if (bemFormada (infixa)){
        printf ("\nExpressao bem-Formada! \n");
        trocaPorParenteses(infixa);
        posfixa = infixaParaPosfixa(infixa);
        printf("\nExpressao posfixa equivalente: %s\n\n", posfixa);
        printf("\nResultado da expressao: %.10f\n\n\n", calculo(posfixa));
    }
    else
        printf ("\nERRO: expressao mal-formada!\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int bemFormada (char string[]){
    char * p;
    int t, n, i;

    n = strlen (string);
    p = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * n);
    t = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (string[i] == '(' || string[i] == '{' || string[i]=='['){
            p[t++] = string[i];
        }
        else if (string[i] == ')'){
            if (t != 0 && p[t - 1] == '('){
                t--;
            }
            else{
                free (p);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if (string[i] == ']'){
            if (t != 0 && p[t - 1] == '['){
                t--;
            }
            else{
                free (p);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if (string[i] == '}'){
            if (t != 0 && p[t - 1] == '{'){
                t--;
            }
            else{
                free (p);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    free (p);
    if (t == 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void trocaPorParenteses(char *string){
    int tam = strlen(string);
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        if(string[i] == '(' || string[i] == '{' || string[i] == '['){
            string[i] = '(';
        }
        else if(string[i] == ')' || string[i] == '}' || string[i] == ']'){
            string[i] = ')';
        }
    }
}

char *infixaParaPosfixa(char infixa[]){
    int t;
    int n, i, j;
    char *posf;
    char *pi;

    n = strlen(infixa);
    posf = malloc( n * sizeof (char));
    pi = malloc( n * sizeof (char));
    t = 0;

    pi[t++] = infixa[0];
    for (j = 0, i = 1; infixa[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        switch (infixa[i]){
            char x;
        case '(':   pi[t++] = infixa[i];
                    break;
        case ')':   while (1){
                        x = pi[--t];
                        if (x == '(') break;
                        posf[j++] = x;
                    } break;
        case '+':   while (1){
                        x = pi[t-1];
                        if (x == '(') break;
                        --t;
                        posf[j++] = x;
                    }
                    pi[t++] = infixa[i];
                    break;
        case '-':   if(infixa[(i+1)] == ' '){
                        while (1){
                            x = pi[t-1];
                            if (x == '(') break;
                            --t;
                            posf[j++] = x;
                        }
                        pi[t++] = infixa[i];
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        posf[j++] = '-';
                        break;
                    }
        case '*':
        case '/':   while (1){
                        x = pi[t-1];
                        if (x == '(' || x == '+' || x == '-') break;
                        --t;
                        posf[j++] = x;
                    }
                    pi[t++] = infixa[i];
                    break;
        default:    posf[j++] = infixa[i];
        }
    }
    free( pi);
    posf[j] = '\0';
    return posf;
}

double calculo(char* posfixa){
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, t=0;
    double a, b, resultado = 0;
    int n = strlen(posfixa);
    char* pi = (char*)calloc(n, sizeof(char));
    pilha* p = NULL;
    if(!posfixa){
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        switch(posfixa[i]){
        case '+':   b = desempilha(&p);
                    a = desempilha(&p);
                    resultado = a + b;
                    printf("\nSomando %.10f + %.10f = %.10f\n\n", a, b,resultado);
                    empilha(&p, criaElemento(resultado));
                    break;
        case '-':   if(posfixa[i+1] != ' '){
                        goto def;
                    }
                    defmenos:
                    b = desempilha(&p);
                    a = desempilha(&p);
                    resultado = a - b;
                    printf("\nSubtraindo %.10f - %.10f = %.10f\n\n", a, b,resultado);
                    empilha(&p, criaElemento(resultado));
                    break;
        case '*':   b = desempilha(&p);
                    a = desempilha(&p);
                    resultado = a * b;
                    printf("\nMultiplicando %.10f * %.10f = %.10f\n\n", a, b,resultado);
                    empilha(&p, criaElemento(resultado));
                    break;
        case '/':   b = desempilha(&p);
                    a = desempilha(&p);
                    resultado = a / b;
                    printf("\nDividindo %.10f / %.10f = %.10f\n\n", a, b,resultado);
                    empilha(&p, criaElemento(resultado));
                    break;
        case ' ':   continue;
        default:
            def:
            /* zera valores de pilha vetor para demais converter para double*/
            for(k=0; k<n; k++){
                pi[k] = 0;
            }
            /* encontra primeira posicao depois do espaco e antes do fim */
            while(posfixa[i] == ' ' && posfixa[i] != '\0'
                    && posfixa[i] != '+'
                    && posfixa[i] != '*'
                    && posfixa[i] != '/') i++;
            j = i;
            t = 0;
            /* pega digitos do numero*/
            while(posfixa[j] != ' ' && posfixa[j] != '\0'
                    && posfixa[j] != '+'
                    && posfixa[j] != '*'
                    && posfixa[j] != '/'){
                pi[t++] = posfixa[j++];
            }
            i = j;
            /* empilha */
            if(atof(pi) != 0){
               printf("Empilha: %s\n", pi);
                empilha(&p, criaElemento(atof(pi)));
            }
            else{
                goto defmenos;
            }
            break;
        }
      /*  mostrarPilha(p);*/
    }
    if(p){
        if(!p->proximo){
            resultado = p->valor;
        }
    }
    free(p);
    return resultado;
}


/* pilha funcoes */
pilha * criaElemento(double valor){
    pilha * e = (pilha*)malloc(sizeof(pilha));
    e->valor = valor;
    e->proximo = NULL;
    return e;
}

void empilha(pilha ** p, pilha* novo){
    if(*p){
        novo->proximo = *p;
        *p = novo;
    }else{
        *p = novo;
    }
}

double desempilha(pilha ** p){
    double valor = 0;
    pilha* aux = *p;
    *p = (*p)->proximo;
    valor = aux->valor;
    free(aux);
    return valor;
}

void mostrarPilha(pilha* p){
    int i = 0;
    pilha* aux = p;
    while(aux){
        printf("Elemento %d ->\t Valor: %.10f\n\n", i++, aux->valor);
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sempre que você acessar o topo da pilha você precisa verificar se o topo da pilha é válido.

Por exemplo, para a expressão "3+7", com esta alteração abaixo não ocorre o erro de segmentação.

```
case '+':
   while (t > 0)
   {
      x = pi[t-1];
      if (x == '(') break;
      --t;
      posf[j++] = x;
   }
   pi[t++] = infixa[i];
   break;
```

Mas é bem provável que existam outros erros deste tipo em seu programa.

Outras coisas que você pode melhorar.

Começar nome de estruturas em maiúsculas:

```
typedef struct
{
   double valor;
   struct pilha *proximo;
} Pilha;
```

Usar "static" para as declarações de função:

```
static int bemFormada (char string[]);
// etc
```

Usar "fgets" em lugar de "gets". Usar "gets" é motivo para demissão por justa causa. :)

Quando você tem vários índices (i, j, t, etc) documentar (ao menos sucintamente) o que fazem cada um desses índices, ou então dar nomes significativos. Afinal de contas, olhando rapidamente, como é que se vai saber para que "i" e "j" são utilizados ? Fica difícil...